# Question regarding the fact that the linear map's rank plus its nullity equals the dimension of its domain

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem: A linear map's rank plus its nullity equals the dimension of its domain.

Let $h:V \rightarrow W$ be linear and let $B_N = \langle \vec B_1, ..., \vec B_k \rangle$ be a basis for the null space. Expand that to a basis $B_V = \langle \vec B_1, ..., \vec B_k, \vec B_{k+1}, ..., \vec B_n \rangle$ for the entire domain, using the fact that linearly independent sets can be expanded to make a basis. We shall show that $B_R = \langle h(\vec B_{k+1}, ..., h(\vec B_n)\rangle$ is a basis for the range space. Then counting the size of the bases gives the result.

To see that $B_R$ is linearly independent, consider $\vec 0_W = c_{k+1}h(\vec B_{k+1}) + ... + c_nh(\vec B_n)$. We have $\vec 0_W = h(c_{k+1} \vec B_{k+1} + ... + c_n \vec B_n)$ and so $c_{k+1} \vec B_{k+1} + ... + c_n \vec B_n$ is in the null space of h. As $B_N$ is a basis for the null space, there are scalars $c_1, ..., c_k$ satisfying this relationship.

$c_1 \vec B_1 + ... + c_k \vec B_k = c_{k+1} \vec B_{k+1} + ... + c_n \vec B_n$

But this is an equation among members of $B_V$, which is a basis for V, so each $c_i$ equals 0. Therefore, $B_R$ is linearly independent.

My first question has to do with the first part of this proof. I'm very confused about this part, so please bear with me if I don't seem to be asking the right question. But how are you allowed to just equate the two different bases together? I understand the logic of the proof, but on an intuitive sense, how can two seemingly completely different bases, one which has been specified to be $B_N$, and one which has been specified to be $B_R$, which supposedly has members of the bases that should NOT belong to $B_N$, be able to equate to each other? Perhaps a concrete example can clarify this point.

My second question belongs in the second part of the proof, so continuing where I left off:

To show that $B_R$ spans the range space consider a member of the range space $h( \vec v)$. Express $\vec v$ as a linear combination $\vec v = c_1 \vec B_1 + ... + c_n \vec B_n$ of members of $B_V$. This gives $h(\vec v) = h(c_1 \vec B_1 + ... + c_n \vec B_n) = c_1 h(\vec B_1) + ... + c_k h(\vec B_k) + c_{k+1} h(\vec B_{k+1}) + ... + c_nh(\vec B_n)$ and since $\vec B_1, ..., \vec B_k$ are in the mull space, we have that $h(\vec v) = \vec 0 + ... + \vec 0 + c_{k+1}h(\vec B_{k+1}) + ... + c_nh(\vec B_n)$. Thus, $h(\vec v)$ is a linear combination of members of $B_R$ and so $B_R$ spans the space.

My question is how in the world can you just replace members of the bases with 0 like that? Where in the world did he get that from? If anything, shouldn't the fact that the nullspace means that $N(h) = h^{-1}(\vec 0_W) =$ { $\vec v E V | h(\vec v) = \vec 0_W$ } (this also a definition from the textbook) mean that the members that would become 0 should be $c_{k+1}h(\vec B_{k+1}) + ... + c_nh(\vec B_n)$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

So first, the basis of a subspace is a linearly independent set, so can be extended to a basis (any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis, this is a special one). So what the proof does is extend a basis of the null space to a basis of the whole space.

Now some of the basis elements form a basis of the null space, so when you apply $h$ to them they go to zero (that's what the null space means - the definition you have is that the null space is the "inverse image" of zero, which simply means it contains every vector in $V$ which maps to zero in $W$). So when $h$ is applied to the vector $v$ written in this special basis, those components go to zero. That was the purpose of starting with the null space in the first place.